# Long waiting time between PHP and Oracle OCI

Tags: php, oracle

I installed XAMPP on Windows server. There are 2 application on my server:

First Application: PHP and MySQL application. This application runs quickly without and waiting time between links/pages.

Second Appilcation: PHP and Oracle application. I use “Oracle Instant Client (OCI) for Windows (32 bit)” to connect Oracle Server (on another machine). I have 8 tables with max 1000 row-data on each table. My queries are very simple. Everyting is working correctly when querying my Oracle database.

But, sometimes I’m waiting more than 20 seconds between pages/links. The is too much time to recieve page. This mostly occurs when entering the site for the first time. Additionaly, it occurs when trying to click on another page or link in application, after waiting 5-10 minutes on a page.

How can I reduce or terminate this delay when connecting Oracle database using OCI?

Comment: comparing mysql on localhost with Oracle on a remote server isn't a good basis for a comparison. That being said, I would expect the oracle connection to be that slow. Have you tried running network tests to see how much overhead there is on the network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are you connecting? If you are using oci_connect, then that's probably a large part of the problem - switch to oci_pconnect.

Failing that, do make sure that DNS A and PTR records are available for both ends (or make sure you're only using ip addresses rather than names to connect).

C.

Comment: I switch oci_connect to oci_pconnect. My problem is seems like solved.